# remove search query after pressing on search button

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, search

I used Android search widget in action bar. When I write my query and press on search button or done, everything works in my search part, but I want to remove that query in search field, or Resetting Search Widget (`SearchView`) value.

For example: if I write "test" after pressing search button I don't want to have this "test" in my search filed. Would you please let me know how can I remove my search query!

Thanks in advance!

I'm using `SearchView` widget from android

Comment: setText(""); perhaps?

Comment: @Arman for removing query?

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is `setQuery()`, documented here:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setQuery(java.lang.CharSequence, boolean)

Here's some example code which clears the search bar after a search is performed. You probably already have an implementation of `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your activity or fragment, so just use the bits you are missing.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

    // Find search item
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_search_item);

    // Get search view attached to item
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            // Perform search here!
            performSearch(query);

            // Clear the text in search bar but (don't trigger a new search!)
            searchView.setQuery("", false);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```